# making 16x1 multiplexer by using two 8x1 multiplexer and one 2x1

Tags: multiplexer

How can I create 16x1 multiplexer by using two 8x1 multiplexer and one 2x1 multiplexer? If it is possible, could you show on image(draw) ?

I've drawn is it right ?

[image]

Comment: Actually if you want the address of the channel to be from top to bottom, the selection pin of the 2:1 mux should be the most significant bit of the address, not the least significant bit (assuming lsb is right).

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show where the select-lines of upper mux is connected to. If those select lines are connected to the select lines of lower mux, then it is correct.

From the figure, it is not quite clear that which line is connected to select-line of 2:1 mux. If you are connecting MSB of the select-lines to 2:1 mux, then the address of the channel will be from top to bottom as Mister Mystère commented. If you are connecting the LSB to 2:1 mux, then the upper mux will be carrying the even addressed channels and lower will carry the odd numbered channels.